# Difference between 頼む and 聞く

Tags: meaning

Is there any difference between 頼む and 聞く?  I've checked a few dictionaries, and it seems to me that maybe 頼む is more humble and 聞く more generic.  Would that be it?  Are they generally interchangeable?

I think they both mean 'ask'.  For example:

友だちに何時と聞きました。
友だちに何時と 頼み ました。

Comment: Could you add what you imagine they both mean or what contexts you think they are interchangeable in? Those two verbs are generally speaking **not** interchangeable.

Comment: @virmaior Done.

Answer (score 9):

「[頼]{たの}む」 means "to ask a favor", "to make a request", etc.

「[聞]{き}く」 means "to ask (a question)"

I cannot think of a situation where 「[頼]{たの}む」 and 「[聞]{き}く」 are interchangeable except for in a ***very*** informal conversation where a question being asked involves a request.  Careful speakers, however, would try to avoid this.

「[車]{くるま}を[貸]{か}してくれる**か**(or **かどうか**)、スミスに**聞いて**みよう。」= "Let's ask Smith if he could lend us his car!"

To say the same thing using 「頼む」, one will need to make a change in the middle part as well.

「車を貸してくれる**よう**(or **ように**)、スミスに**頼んで**みよう。」

Careful speakers would not swap 「頼む」 for 「聞く」 or vice versa in the example sentences above.  That, of course, means that some people actually would do that.

Let's take a look at your sentences.

「友だちに何時と聞きました。」＝「友達に『何時？』と**聞きました**。」 = "I asked my friend what time it was."

This is a good sentence and you could NOT use 「頼む」 here.

「友だちに何時と**頼みました**。」

This makes no sense, I am afraid.  Where is the request that is being made?

To use 「頼む」 correctly, one could alter the sentence to:

「友達に5時に来るように頼みました。」 or

「友達に5時に来てと頼みました。」

Naturally, you could NOT use 「聞く」 in these sentences.

= "I asked my friend to come at 5 o'clock."

Answer (score 5):

[聞]{き}く refers to a **request for information**. Note that this particular usage of the word is often written as 訊く as well. Examples:

- [友]{とも}だちに[何時]{なんじ}と[聞]{き}きました。 (Asked a friend what time it was.)
- [自分]{じぶん}の[胸]{むね}に[聞]{き}け ("Ask your heart." / "Look inside yourself.")

[頼]{たの}む is all about a **request for action**. Examples:

- [代筆]{だいひつ}を頼む (Ask someone to write a letter. / "Please write a letter [for me].")
- [口外]{こうがい}しないよう頼む ("Don't reveal this [secret].")

As you can see with these definitions, 「友だちに何時と頼みました」 doesn't really make any sense. I don't know of any examples I've seen where the two words can be switched out while still retaining the same meaning. This is a good example of the fact that even though two words may *translate* similarly, that doesn't necessarily mean that they function similarly in the original language. :)

(other example sentences from goo[辞書]{じしょ}: [聞く](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/51102/m0u/%E8%A8%8A%E3%81%8F/), [頼む](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/138138/m0u/))

Answer (score 2):

聞く means 'ask (a question)'.

> 友達に何時か聞きました。I asked a friend what time it was.

頼む means 'ask someone to do something'.

> 友達に助けてくれと頼みました。 I asked a friend to help me.

Comment: I think you're missing a particle on that first sentence or else you should change it to 聞いた if you're going for informal.

Comment: @virmaior 「何時か聞きました」、「何時かと聞きました」、「何時か聞いた」、「何時かと聞いた」... どれも使えますよ。

Comment: But isn't skipping the と somewhat casual or is it acceptable as some sort of absorption under the か? Would it be okay for me to do that in business e-mails?

Comment: @virmaior ～か聞きました。/～か聞きます。 is not informal. For example, you would say 何時か聞いてみます rather than 何時かと聞いてみます. in a business email. It's not absorption. It's  「～か+聞く」「～か+尋ねる」 'ask if~' 'ask what~' etc.